# parse and concatenate phrases

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a file dump which has the records of individuals:

```
.....Detail....account=xxxxx,......state=yyyyy,....
.....Detail....account=aaaaa,......state=bbbbb,....
```

What would be a way to extract the 2 phrases concatenated together using awk,sed or grep?
Would it be possible in a single-pass command line?

Expected output(delimiter does not matter):

```
xxxxx-yyyyy
aaaaa-bbbbb
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: *2 phrases concatenated together* - which phrases, show how should  look the expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The details about the input data are a bit vague, but the following sed filter will probably have the desired effect, and could most likely be tweaked to do so otherwise:

```
s/.*account=\([^,]*\).*state=\([^,]*\),.*/\1-\2/
```

Comment: My original posting was made concurrently with another. I edited it since then to make it more complete. The system seems only to make the time of the most recent edit obvious ....

Comment: My answer has a strong caveat.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F'[=,]' '{print $2"-"$4}' file 

xxxxx-yyyyy
aaaaa-bbbbb
```

Answer (score 0):

@IUnknown: I believe that .....(dots) in your Input_file are the data, could you please try following and let me know if this helps.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /=/){split($i, A,"=");Q=Q?Q"-"A[2]:A[2]}};print Q;Q=""}'  Input_file
```

It considers that you need only those values which are having = in them and you want their second values, let me know if this helps you.